# AsyncTeleBot iterator over messages

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

Is there a method in the `AsyncTeleBot` library that can iterate through all the messages in a channel and select only certain keywords?

I looked in the documentation, but did not find it. Or I ask you to suggest a library for `Python` with the `Telegram API`, which has the above method, which the bot can use.